# Unable to Flash eMMC from SD Card BeagleBone Black8

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

I am currently trying to flash Debian to my BeagleBone Black in accordance with this instruction:
http://derekmolloy.ie/write-a-new-image-to-the-beaglebone-black/

However, following the "Knightrider" light sequence, instead of all of the lights staying lit solid, they all blink (all on then off, 250ms delay, all on then off, 750ms delay). I can't find a case of this happening anywhere else. I have walked through the flashing procedure many times already with no luck.

Comment: Which Hardware revision of BBB do you have? What size of SD card did you use? Usually it's a sticker on the outside of the P8 port. https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack#Board_Revisions_and_Changes Do you have a USB-UART adapter that you could attach to the debug port (not the mini USB port!)?